# UIImageView.image works for iPhone 5/ios7 but not for iPhone 4/ios 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios7

So I am having the user login to facebook and then I'm saving their fb photo to my app. This works perfectly on my iPhone 5 with iOS 7 but I just wanted to see how things were looking the smaller screen so I got out my iPhone 4 with iOS 5. Haven't tried iOS 6. I'm very new to objective c/xcode and started development with the xcode 5 beta and iOS 7. Is there something I need to do different for versions < 7

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // As chuncks of the image are received, we build our data file
    [imageData appendData:data];
}

// Called when the entire image is finished downloading
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // Set the image in the header imageView
    profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    NSLog(@"%@",profilePic.image);
}
```

EDIT:

imageData has the data and profilePic.image returns a uiimage with NSLog

Also, do I need to make a new storyboard for iPhones before the 5?

Answer (score 0):

In every release of iOS there are usually quite a few changes, and it's not uncommon for an application that works in a particular release to breaks in another.

My suggestion is that you go through the Apple release notes for versions 6 and 7 and check if there is something that would work on iOS 7 and not in iOS 5.

BTW, do you have iOS 5 in you iPhone 4 for a particular reason ?

My guess is that there should be not so many user using such an older version, I upgraded mine to iOS7, and I suppose that the vast majority of people that have not done so would have at least version 6.

Comment: Supporting different iOS versions and phones is often a business requirement.  I know my team has to support iOS5.1 for the time being.

Comment: Ok, since you stated you are new to iOS development I was curious.

Comment: My 4 has been sitting around unused for a while so I never updated to 6. Now I can't so I'd rather one device with 7 and one with 5 than two devices with 7